# Creating ItemTemplate for DataGrid with C#

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Here is the XAML. I want to do the same thing with C#.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Address">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Address}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Please help.

Comment: `Here is the XAML. I want to do the same thing with C#.` = Wrong. You're not supposed to create datatemplates in code, and if you need to do so, you almost invariably end up creating a string with the XAML and using a XAMLReader to parse that. Still, that's plain wrong and completely unnecesary UNLESS you have a really good reason to.

Comment: @HighCore - I had to create Templates dynamically because of I don't exactly know what kind of objects will be bind to this. I want to have some kind of UIElement for a specific types. Is it possible to do with XAML? Let me know if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create `DataTemplate` in code you should use `FrameworkElementFactory` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx)).

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Loaded="myDataGrid_Loaded">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="templateColumnAddress" Header="Address" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-behind:

```
public void myDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElementFactory tbHolder = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
    tbHolder.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("Address"));          
    var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    dataTemplate.VisualTree = tbHolder;
    dataTemplate.DataType = typeof(DataGridTemplateColumn);
    templateColumnAddress.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
}
```